# Windows explorer crashes when trying to enter a specific RAID volume

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-server-2003

On Windows Server 2003, I have three RAID volumes, appearing as C, E, and F. In explorer, when I left click on C or E, I enter the drive as expected. However, when doing the same in F, explorer crashes with error 1000, followed by 1002 (information not error in the log). If I right click on any of the drives, I don't get any problem. If I access the same drive as a share in explorer via \\f$, I also don't run into problems. How do I fix this?

Comment: capture a crash dump with procdump: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-9-ProcDump an share the dmp

Comment: I did not get a crashdump, but solved the problem by moving a file in F: to a subfolder. This file was a zipfile that when I rightclicked it wanted to open Internet Explorer, moving it caused it to behave normally.